# Spring Batch: Step Partitioning OutOfMemory error

Tags: java, spring, spring-batch

I have a step partitioned spring batch and I am using **JdbcPagingItemReader** for reading data in chunk and processing.

The batch is running fine with 3000 records. But if the load increased to 6000 then we are frequently getting OutOfMemoryError

```
Exit FailureExeptions : [java.lang.OutOfMemoryError, org.springframework.batch.core.JobExecutionException: Partition handler returned an unsuccessful step, java.lang.OutOfMemoryError, java.lang.OutOfMemoryError, java.lang.OutOfMemoryError]
```

The average load of the batch would be 3000 records but max could be 6000 in exceptional case. We are testing our batch with 6000 records.

**Current Activity:**

1) We are trying to get the heap dump to analyze the issue further.

2) Looking other options like increasing heap size. Existing setup min is 128 MB and max is 512 MB

**The job xml file:**

```
<import resource="../config/batch-context.xml" />
<import resource="../config/database.xml" />

<job id="partitionJob" xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/batch">
    <step id="masterStep" parent="abstractPartitionerStagedStep">
        <partition step="slave" partitioner="rangePartitioner">
            <handler grid-size="5" task-executor="taskExecutor" />
        </partition>
    </step>
</job>

<bean id="abstractPartitionerStagedStep" abstract="true">
    <property name="listeners">
        <list>
            <ref bean="updatelistener" />
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="updatelistener" class="com.test.springbatch.model.UpdateFileCopyStatus" />

<step id="slave" xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/batch">
    <tasklet>
        <chunk reader="pagingItemReader" writer="flatFileItemWriter"
            processor="itemProcessor" commit-interval="1" retry-limit="0"
            skip-limit="100">
            <skippable-exception-classes>
                <include class="java.lang.Exception" />
            </skippable-exception-classes>
        </chunk>
    </tasklet>
</step>

<bean id="rangePartitioner" class="com.test.springbatch.partition.RangePartitioner">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
</bean>

<bean id="taskExecutor" class="org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor">
    <property name="corePoolSize" value="5" />
    <property name="maxPoolSize" value="5" />
    <property name="queueCapacity" value="100" />
    <property name="allowCoreThreadTimeOut" value="true" />
    <property name="keepAliveSeconds" value="60" />
</bean>

<bean id="itemProcessor" class="com.test.springbatch.processor.CaseProcessor" scope="step">
    <property name="threadName" value="#{stepExecutionContext[name]}" />
</bean>

<bean id="pagingItemReader" class="org.springframework.batch.item.database.JdbcPagingItemReader" scope="step">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    <property name="saveState" value="false" />
    <property name="queryProvider">
        <bean class="org.springframework.batch.item.database.support.SqlPagingQueryProviderFactoryBean">
            <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
            <property name="selectClause" value="SELECT *" />
            <property name="fromClause" value="FROM ( SELECT CASE_NUM ,CASE_STTS_CD, UPDT_TS,SBMT_OFC_CD, SBMT_OFC_NUM,DSTR_CHNL_CD,APRV_OFC_CD,APRV_OFC_NUM,SBMT_TYP_CD, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY CASE_NUM) AS rownumber FROM TSMCASE WHERE PROC_IND ='N' ) AS data" />
            <property name="whereClause" value="WHERE rownumber BETWEEN :fromRow AND :toRow " />
            <property name="sortKey" value="CASE_NUM" />
        </bean>
    </property>

    <property name="parameterValues">
        <map>
            <entry key="fromRow" value="#{stepExecutionContext[fromRow]}" />
            <entry key="toRow" value="#{stepExecutionContext[toRow]}" />
        </map>
    </property>
    <property name="pageSize" value="100" />
    <property name="rowMapper">
        <bean class="com.test.springbatch.model.CaseRowMapper" />
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="flatFileItemWriter" class="com.test.springbatch.writer.FNWriter" scope="step" />
```

**My Questions:**

1. Job is running fine with 3000 records then why it is throwing OOM error if the load is 6000 records even through I am using chunk oriented processing? Does JdbcPagingItemReader caches anything internally?
2. Is my job configurations looks fine? Is there any scope of improvement in the job configurations?

Comment: Can you provide the full stacktrace for the OOM error?

Comment: Your config looks ok, IMO. The only thing that catches my eye is commit-interval="1". that is single item processing and not batch-processing. However, this doesn't explain the OOM. Ist the behavior differently if you change the pageSize=100 to pageSize=500 or even 1000? Have you tried to use VisualVM in order to figure out what kind of objects are beeing allocated?

Comment: I took heap dump and analysed with IBM Heap Analyzer, there is no suspected object from spring batch listed. So I decided to test the batch with page size 25 and it ran successfully. Finally we have decided to increase the heap size to 1 GB. Tested with 6K records no issues.